# Clarification with a prescription for blood tests

Tags: dermatology, blood-tests, hairloss

I have a pro long condition of hair loss. I consulted a dermatologist and he gave me list of blood tests which I should do before the next consultation. I have difficulty in reading one of the items in the list (so does the people in the laboratory and the nurse). Unfortunately the dermatologist is on vacation and I can not ask him.

[image]

**Can anyone help me reading the 5th item in the below list**?

**Hints**:

- These tests were prescribed to diagnose the cause of hair loss
- The tests should be taken on a specific dates after a period

The 5th item looks like the word 'total'. I did bit of googling and founf out that there are blood tests called free T3 and T4 and Total T3 and T4.